# Populating Listview with data from more ArrayLists

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

Well, like the title says I want to populate a ListView with the data that is in multiple arrays. The ListItem structure looks like:

*Person Name

*01234567

*Boulevard of Broken Dreams, NY

---

and all the data for person name, phone number and adress is in seperate arraylists.
So, I have arraylists personsArr, phonesArr, adressArr and I want to display that data in the ListView for each person that have a phone number and adress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single class that have String persons, phones, address...

[See NewsBean.java](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html)

```
public class Items {

private String name;
private int phoneNo;
private String address;
```

}

-Create getters and Setters Methods for name,phoneNo,address

**Now add data in list**

```
List<Items> list = new ArrayList<Items>();

 Items objItems = new Items();
 objItems.setName("Name"); 
 objItems.setPhoneNo(12345);
 objItems.setaddress("adress");

 list.add(objItems);
```

**Now get data from list**

```
Items objItems =(Items)list.get(index);
String name = objItems.getName(); 
int phoneNo=objItems.getPhoneNo();
String address=objItems.getaddress();
```

Comment: Thanke you for your answer, Samir. Now I have better application structure with Person class, but I still need to display Person's data in ListView. This is a similiar layout of ListView row: [link](http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/listview_states.png)